# Google Maps Polylines and the International Date Line

Tags: google-maps

I have a bit of a problem persuading polylines to go around the world in the direction I want. As far as I can see from googling the issue, there used to be a problem on older versions of the Google Maps API whereby polylines would not cross the International Date Line (or more strictly, the 180 meridian). Later versions have "corrected" the problem.

However, I want to **prevent** polylines crossing the 180 meridian. [This link](http://myrootsmap.com/map.php?origin=14&mapver=oms) shows the reason why. Although the distance from Hawaii to Kenya is shortest across the Pacific, this map would look better if the polyline took the path across the Atlantic.

As my polyline is defined simply by the lat/lng of the ends, I don't see how I can readily change it within my code. So it seems like it needs something within the API itself but I haven't been able to find it. Have I missed something?

Comment: Although this question is pretty old and the link does no longer work, I would be interested in whether you found a solution. I guess, that the API always connects the 2 endpoints of each line segment using the shorter of the 2 possible ways. (Even for two close-by points, there would always be a second way around the globe) So one solution could be to calculate intermediate points and add these to the line.

Comment: I took @user2808624's suggestion, it just needs the one mid-point, but remember to take the geodesic midpoint if you don't want a crooked line.